# need help in figuring out equation & graph for a matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix defined by $$A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0\\0 & 2
\end{bmatrix},$$ and $(x,y)$ satisfy an equation $x^2+y^2=1$. If $(x',y')$ is the image of $(x,y)$ under the matrix $A$. $$\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y'\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},$$
find the equation of $(x',y')$ and sketch its graph.

---

I need help in figuring this out for my linear algebra class, I tried going through my text book but no luck & google search but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ into the equation and simplifying gives you

$$\begin{bmatrix} x^{\prime}\\ y^{\prime}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3x \\ 2y\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, $x^{\prime} = 3x \implies x=\frac{1}{3}x^{\prime}$ and $y^{\prime} = 2y\implies y = \frac{1}{2}y^{\prime}$.  Since you're given that $x^2+y^2=1$, we now see that

$$\left(\frac{x^{\prime}}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y^{\prime}}{2}\right)^2 = 1 \implies \frac{{x^{\prime}}^2}{9} + \frac{{y^{\prime}}^2}{4}=1$$

I hope that you can take things from here in plotting the graph.